# most efficient way calling a specific method by key || refactor method calling switch statements

Tags: java, methods, reflection, switch-statement, refactoring

I have algorithm that give me an Integer. 
Based on this Integer, i want to call a method. 
Every Integer is unique (like a primary key in a database) and has 1 method to call. Every method returns the same datatype. The methods are all in the same class and get called in this class.

After hours of searching, i only get this 2 solutions, but i don't know which is the "better"? (running time, resources)

switch solution:
first idea, but feels not very good

```
switch (code) {
    case 1:
        nextOperation = doMethod1();
        break;

    case 2:
        nextOperation = doMethod2();
        break;

    //many more cases...

    default:
        break;
    }

public MyObject doMethod1(MyObject myObject){
    //do something with operation
    return myObject;
    }
```

reflection solution: maybe bad running time(?)

```
    try{
        String methodName = "doMethod" + Integer.toString(operation.getOperationCode()); 
        //operation.getOperationCode() same like code in switch solution
        Method method = this.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parametertype);
        nextOperation = (MyObject) method.invoke(this, parameter);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        LogReport.writeLog(e.toString()); //own Log-Report filewriter
    }
```

Is there maybe a better way for my problem or other solutions? 
If you can give me a little hint, i would be very glad.

Comment: The other big problem with reflection is that it's going to hurt static analysis. You won't be able to ask your IDE to show you all the places where `doMethod1` is called.

Comment: These two ways are different. In the first one you call the methods on `this` and in the second you call them on `nextOperation`. The second one also doesn't change the value of `nextOperation`.

Comment: Are the codes consecutive? Then you can just use an array (or possibly an unmodifiable list) of either `MethodHandle`s or some functions that call the methods.

Comment: invoke( Object obj, Object... args ) and i thought obj is the object in which i store my returns, like nextOperation = doMethod();

Comment: @Phil The first object is the instance the method is called on (or null in case of a static method). What is the `parameter` you have in the reflective version?

Comment: @Bubletan the parameter is an own created object (class), for my better unterstanding lets say its a Integer, so the parameter is Integer and the return of doMethod is also a Integer

Comment: @Phil I do understand that it's some kind of object, but there is no such thing in the switch approach. You should provide complete examples to make helping easier.

Comment: @Bubletan It was my bad, i never used reflections before. I have edit the code so that the reflection solution will work. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A third option would be to build a map from numbers to `Runnables` and look up the method to call. I'm not sure how the running time would compare, but I imagine it would be faster than using reflection.

```
Map<Integer, Runnable> methodMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
methodMap.put(1, () -> doMethod1());
methodMap.put(2, () -> doMethod2());
methodMap.put(3, () -> doMethod3());
// ... and so on ...

// look up the method and run it:
Runnable method = methodMap.get(code);
if (method != null) {
    method.run();
}
```

I'm using a `ConcurrentHashMap` just in case this map needs to be modified on the fly while your program is running, but if you build the map just once at the beginning and then never modify it, a plain `HashMap` might do just as well. I used lambdas to create `Runnables` to call each method.

The code to build the map would still be quite lengthy. You could shorten it by using reflection to help build the map. That would be slower, but you would pay the penalty for reflection just once when the map was built, instead of each time you need to dispatch a method by number.

Note: Here is another way to add the methods to the map without using lambdas:

```
methodMap.put(1, new Runnable() { public void run() { doMethod1(); } });
methodMap.put(2, new Runnable() { public void run() { doMethod2(); } });
methodMap.put(3, new Runnable() { public void run() { doMethod3(); } });
// etc.
```

That is how it would be done with anonymous inner classes; the lambdas are essentially anonymous methods that take no arguments `()` and the expression after the `->` is the code to call (such as `doMethod1()`); the compiler sees that this is being passed to the `put` method of a `Map<Integer, Runnable>` and takes the anonymous method to be the `run` method of the `Runnable`, and uses that code to create the `Runnable`.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the map will change at runtime if a switch is an applicable alternative.

Comment: Why does the map change at runtime?

Comment: @Phil I don't know that it will. I was just being extra careful because I don't know what the rest of your code might be doing. The best way to do it would be to build the map once, and then never change it, only read from it.

Comment: Ok, i get it, but i never used lambdas before (i just read about them). For my better understanding, it would be nice if you can give me a long expression for one.

Comment: I've added an example of how you could do it using anonymous inner classes instead, and an explanation of how lambdas can take the place of them.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, i can't use lambdas because android compiles in Java 7. Would you still recommend to use a HashMap or a switch? (because the tipping effort without lambdas is nearly the same)

Comment: @Phil anonymous classes are fine and the idea still makes sense with Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a:

```
Map<Integer, Supplier<Operation>> map = new ...;
map.put(1, () -> doMethod1());
map.put(2, () -> doMethod2());
```

And then call:

```
nextOperation = map.get(operationCode).get();
```

Comment: Style note: either `() -> doMethod1` or `MyClass::doMethod1` will work, I think.

Comment: @yshavit `MyClass::doMethod1` will only work if the method is static.

Comment: How about `this::doMethod1`

Comment: @shmosel If the method is non-static you would need to have a `Function<MyClass, Operation>` to be able to pass `this` as a parameter (unless you create a separate map for every instance). This would allow using a method reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you could try to call the methods using lambda, mapping them to an integer HashMap.

**Interface:**

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void excecute();
}
```

**Initializing methods:**

```
private int i = 0;
...
...
HashMap<Integer, MyInterface> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(0, () -> {
    i = doMethod0();
});
```

**Invoking methods:**

```
myMap.get(i).excecute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it (which is compatible with Java 7, although I don't know if it is supported on Android) is to use `MethodHandles`. They provide the advantage of reflection in that you don't have to write all the code to populate the map (although it would be possible to write a script to generate the code, since that presumably only needs to be done once), but they are faster than reflection since the access checks are performed ahead of time, when the lookup is performed.

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

Map<Integer, MethodHandle> handleByNumber = new HashMap<>();
MethodHandles.Lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(MyObject.class, MyObject.class);

int number = 1; // find all doMethodN methods from 1 up to whatever
while (true) {
    try {
        MethodHandle mh = lookup.findStatic(MyClass.class, "doMethod" + number, mt);
        handles.put(number, mh);
        number++;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the methods are `static`, that the class the methods are in is named `MyClass`, and that the methods take and return `MyObject` as in the question, but the question isn't consistent on that. These would have to be changed.

If the methods are not static, `lookup.findVirtual` would be used instead of `lookup.findStatic`.

To call a method by number, where `obj` is the parameter:

```
MethodHandle mh = handles.get(code);
if (mh != null) {
    try {
        MyObject result = (MyObject) mh.invokeExact(obj);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // or other handling as appropriate
    }
}
```

If the methods aren't static, the receiver (the object you're calling the method on) needs to be provided in the call:

```
MyObject result = (MyObject) mh.invokeExact(receiver, obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for this other good solution and runtime improvement. (Never heared of `MethodHandle` before) But why should i use a Map, when i get the method directly by `mh.invokeExact()`? And it seems that i can't use `MethodHandle` in Android, the hole `java.lang.invoke` didn't work...

Comment: @Phil I suppose you could look it up each time instead of storing it in a map. I'm not sure how that would affect the performance. Anyway, it sounds like you can't use it. The one with Runnables was about the same speed as MethodHandles in some tests on my laptop.